# Read a positive integer size and plot number triangles based on input

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and have been trying to mess around with some basic things to increase my understanding of the language.  Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

Write a program to read a positive integer size and then plot triangles based on this input. Suppose you type the number 5, you should plot a triangle as follows(line 1 prints 4 spaces and number 5; line 2 prints 3 spaces and numbers 4 and 5, etc.):

```
      5
    45
  345
2345
```

So far I have this :

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 class Triangle
 {
  public static void main(String [] args)
   {
        int number, space;

      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter The Number:");
      number = in.nextInt();


         for (int i=1; i<=number; i++)
         {
             for (int j = number; j>=1; j--)
             {
               if (j>i) 
                   System.out.print("_");
               else
                   System.out.print(j);

         }
         System.out.println();}}}
```

I know I'm close, but don't want to mess anything up and end up further from the solution.  It seems that I just need to switch my starting and ending numbers.

If anyone could offer help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your output is does not match according to question. first line contains 6 spaces, not 4. last line 12345 is missing. which is right?

Comment: Don't worry about messing things up. You can always backup a version of the java file and revert to it if needed. If you use an IDE you can reload previous version from history.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the two following nested loops:

```
for (int i=number-1; i >= 0; --i) {
    String spaces = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", " ");
    String nums = "";
    for (int j=i+1; j <= number; ++j) {
        nums += String.valueOf(j);
    }

    System.out.println(spaces + nums);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some changes I have done and mentioned in comments and it works perfect!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 class Triangle
 {
  public static void main(String [] args)
   {
        int number, space;

      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter The Number:");
      number = in.nextInt();


         for (int i=1; i<=number; i++)
         {
             for (int j = number; j>=1; j--)
             {
               if (j>i) 
                   System.out.print(" ");           //print space instead of _
               else
                   System.out.print(number+1-j);    //print number+1-j which will be you decreasing Sequence

         }
         System.out.println();}}}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I'm sure this will not be the last questions I have... :)

Comment: Hehe ! As a programmer everytime you should have a question!.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code : instead of printing out the j counter:

```
System.out.print(j);
```

You want to print

```
System.out.print(number -(j-1));
```

An alternative solution:

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {

     int number =5, numberOfSpaces;

      for (int row=1; row<= number ; row++) {

          numberOfSpaces = number - row;

          for (int column=1; column<= number ; column++) {

              if(column<=numberOfSpaces) {

                System.out.print(" ");

              }else {

                 System.out.print(column);
              }
          }

          System.out.println();
      }

   }
```

A shorter version which does exactly the same :

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {

     int number =5, numberOfSpaces;

    for (int row=1; row<= number ; row++) {

          numberOfSpaces = number - row;

          for (int column=1; column<= number ; column++) {

                System.out.print( (column<=numberOfSpaces) ? " " : column);
          }

          System.out.println();
     }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just the way you wanted: easy to understand. enjoy!

```
 import java.util.*;
    class Triangle
    {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            int number, space;
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter The Number:");
            number = in.nextInt();
            for (int i=1; i<=number; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j<=number; j++)
                {
                    if (j>number-i) /**the only problem you were having in your code was that it was printing it in reverse.. I reversed the loop and modified` to do so*/
                        System.out.print(j);
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```